# Unslider.js move function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

the plugin Unslider have a function like this:

```
//  Move Unslider to a slide index
        this.move = function(index, cb) {
            //  If it's out of bounds, go to the first slide
            if(!this.items.eq(index).length) index = 0;
            if(index < 0) index = (this.items.length - 1);

            var target = this.items.eq(index);
            var obj = {height: target.outerHeight()};
            var speed = cb ? 5 : this.opts.speed;

            if(!this.ul.is(':animated')) {          
                //  Handle those pesky dots
                _.el.find('.dot:eq(' + index + ')').addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');

                this.el.animate(obj, speed) && this.ul.animate($.extend({left: '-' + index + '00%'}, obj), speed, function(data) {
                    _.current = index;
                    $.isFunction(_.opts.complete) && !cb && _.opts.complete(_.el);
                });
            }
        };
```

have any ideia of how i can make the unslider move allways to left, and not back for the first slide after reach the last? see example here: http://unslider.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this will be a future update, answered by the own developer @idiot

dev branch {infinite: true }

https://github.com/idiot/unslider/tree/dev